What is vertically coupled alignment in source code?
Formatting multiline statements is an arcane art that most auto formatters and style guides can't help you with. One habit I picked up is to ensure renaming things wont cause multiple lines to need to move due to what I thought was called vertical coupling. However, when I go searching for this term Google is no help.
Example code:
Widget widget = WidgetBuilder.build()
                             .color("green")
                             .sprockets(13);

Note the dots are vertically coupled and depend on the first line. Anything gets renamed in the first line and the rest must move to preserve the vertical coupling.
However, this could have been laid out like so:
Widget widget = WidgetBuilder
    .build()
    .color("green")
    .sprockets(13)
;

This avoids the need to reposition following lines after a rename. Also avoids mixing tabs and spaces if you've been cursed with tabs.
This issue isn’t just about laying out builders. Here’s another example:
void MyClass::myFunction(const MyObject& obj,
                         const string& s1,
                         const string& s2,
                         const string& s3) {
    return;
}

Which could be laid out as:
void MyClass::myFunction(
        const MyObject& obj,
        const string& s1,
        const string& s2,
        const string& s3
) {
    return;
}

Steve Jessop once took me to task over this issue.
Does this concern have a better name? I could have sworn I saw this in a book once.
Anyway, is it better to avoid forcing people to adjust many lines just to rename something or better to leave it as it was?

"coupling" sounds wrong, but can't find anything on google, so i guess its called "orange-indentation" now

Orangentation perhaps?

So you don't mean simply "vertical alignment", or do you?

Elastic tabstops are one way to get such nice alignment, without playing with spaces to align things manually. The alternative is only caring about alignment at the start of a line, and you have shown a good style for that.

I prefer stacking arguments to a function like that, it makes things easier to read.

@DocBrown total vertical alignment would have s1 lined up with obj. The way Joshua Bloch does his code. I'm just talking about decoupling the indentation so the first line can't force it to change. But thanks for the reminder.

For the record: If you said "vertical coupling" to me without any extra context, I would assume you were talking about coupling of software components across layers (as opposed to "horizontal coupling", within layers). But also, I'd understand what you mean if you followed the statement by some clarifying comments that would do away with that initial assumption.

One rule of thumb I would leverage is that code is read far more often than it is written.  I would only make a style choice that makes writing easier if it has no negative effect on readability.

@CortAmmon I get what you're saying (and it's probably a good rule of thumb), but I'd argue that readability differences in this particular case are trivial (and if they do not appear so, it's only because of people being accustomed to one or the other type of formatting, and arguing about that is pretty much bikeshedding).

Isn't this fixed by the default VS rule that says something like "...should all be on the same line or all be on a separate line" ? Or it could be a StyleCop rule. The rule addresses this problem: not just less work to reformat but diffs on mutations will look cleaner in version control and show the significant change only. I am not aware of a dedicated name for this issue.

This is the sort of thing that I'm fine with iff some tool does it automatically. Does mean that the whole team needs the same tools

@Caleth Been at this for decades. In industry, education, and government. Have yet to be on a single team where everyone used the same tools. Anyway, I endeavor to write code that is less dependent on tools. Not more.

I've used “endline layout” for years because it's precedented, but the lack of useful Google hits suggests it's a very poor term: it's not strongly suggestive of meaning; about the only thing going for it aside from precedent is that it's eminently googleable!  IMO “vertically coupled alignment” is probably better overall.
A problem you didn't mention: it's worse for version control: more merge conflicts and misleading blame.
How I do it: if you can't fit the open and close of a delimiter pair (<>,[],(),{}) on the same line, break after the open and use standard indentation everywhere.

Note: at the time when I wrote this answer, the question title did not contain the term "alignment", only "vertical coupling".
I think most of us will agree there is no "perfect solution" to the described issue of readability vs. changing indentation in context of renaming, so let me focus on the answerable part of this question, the terminology.
What we see here are different kinds of multi-part statements, which we want to layout as multi-line blocks. This leads to the effect of vertically coupled alignment.
(I would not call this "vertical coupling", exactly for the reasons mentioned by Filip Milovanović in a comment: this term can be confused with it's meaning in regards to components and layers).
Now, there are two main kind of layout styles for multi-line blocks, both are described in Steve McConnell's classic book "Code complete (1st edition)" in chapter 18.3 ("Layout Styles"):

Endline Layout (as in the initial examples of the question)

Pure Blocks (as in the reformatted version of the examples)


When using "Endline Layout", the vertically coupled alignment leads to the necessity of changing indentation in case of renaming. Pure Blocks avoid this.
A little bit later in chapter 18.3, McConnell wrote:

In short, avoid endline layout because it's inaccurate, it's hard to apply consistently, and it's hard to maintain.

To be fair, at this point of the book, McConnell had blocks of multiple statements in mind, with some kind of begin/end brackets. Later, in chapter 18.5 ("Laying Out Individual Statements"), he presented different forms of indentation for routine-call continuation lines, either

by using standard indentation, or
by aligning under the first argument of the routine, or
by using one individual line per argument - including the first.

And to cite him finally about these layouts:

Any of the three options for formatting multiple-line routine calls works all right, if you use it consistently.


Very nice find! I have the Second edition of code complete. It has “Layout Styles” in 31.3. Finishes by recommending pure block in Visual Basic and Java. Fence sits about it in C++.

Excellent answer.  A small note: the bulletted choices are not mutually exclusive; you can use standard indentation and one individual line per argument (not advocating for or against this combination).


Anyway, is it better to avoid forcing people to adjust many lines just to rename something or better to leave it as it was?

Neither. It's better to have a tool1 enforce either (or neither) style, and not spend any thought on it yourself. The formatter configuration should be stored alongside the code, and preferably part of the integration process should enforce the formatting.


It doesn't have to be a single tool, if multiple can understand a shared configuration.


So true.  Life is too short for manually formatting code.  More cost efficient to let automation do it.

Yes yes, but remember, someone has to write those tools.

It's not true that styles are equivalent, even if you have enforcement.  Vertically coupled alignment leads to larger commit diffs, more merge conflicts, poor use of space and inconsistent source code density.
Also, a nit: you want automatic application of a style, not just enforcement (e.g. commit blocking or merge blocking) which is a huge inconvenience.

@DaveAbrahams I'd rather have a codebase that was consistent, and a tool dealing with it, than have the "perfect" style as applied by each dev. Once you have a tool enforcing it, it's really easy to have buy-in for a tool applying it. Different people will have different preferences as to when that tool runs

@Caleth I have no argument with that.  I'm not saying which style you choose is more important than enforcement (although I maintain that mere enforcement is much worse than automatic application, and might even be worse than no enforcement).  I'm simply addressing the idea that what style you choose doesn't matter at all.  There are objective factors that make vertically coupled alignment worse than other choices.

You might search for Wrapping, Indentation, and Alignment.  I use DevExpress' CodeRush to format my C# code, and these settings are under "Wrapping".  Visual Studio also does a lighter version of this and it's under Indentation in the settings.
Here's an example CodeRush setting:


This seems to create what I'm trying to avoid.
